# REGEX to capture sentences with quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I am having trouble putting together a regex to match quotes and sentences. Here are the (simplified) specs I am trying to meet:

- A sentence is a chain of characters followed by a punctuation mark (a dot, to keep things simple) or a newline.
- A quote is a chain of characters between two `"`.
- Each sentence should be a new match.
- A sentence can contain quotes, and quotes can contain sentences. Only the last sentence in a quote should end the capture.

So far I have come up with this: `\s*((?:("[^"]*")|[^.\n])*\.+"?)\s*`

Test case: [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/rT3iZ4/1)

As you can see I can't properly separate quotes from sentences. For example:

§2: `"Your lordship," Mya informed Lord Robert, "Lady Waynwood’s banners have been seen an hour down the road. She will be here soon, with your cousin Harry. Will you want to greet them"` Should be a full match, but the regex gives me three and captures the next paragraph.

§3: `"They were invited," she said uncertainly, "for the tourney. I don’t..."` Should stop as a full match , but the regex goes on to capture `Alayne closed her book.`

I can't figure out what is going wrong, any help would be very much appreciated.

EDIT: [DESIRED OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7g8L.png)

Comment: You have programmed the regex to detect single dot end, therfore  **"They were invited," she said uncertainly, "for the tourney. I don’t..." Alayne closed her book.** is a full sentence which is correct

Comment: Your regex is doing its job. your example §2 would not be a full match but three as per your required rules. Since there are puncuation marks after 'road' and 'Harry'.

Comment: Doesn't `\.+` mean "a dot, between one and unlimited times"?

Comment: @ArathiSreekumar My 4th rule is: sentences containing multiple quotes should be a unique match. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: True, but your puntuation isnt inside a quote. And that means, your sentence ends at the punctuation, and doesnt contain multiple quotes.

Comment: I still maintain my point that it should be a full match since the punctuation is in the quote right after 'road'

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your desired output. Your 1st example has 3 separate sentences, and two separate quotes. Why would you expect a full match?

Comment: Because per the 4th rule, a sentence can contain quotes, and when it does, it should be captured as a single meta-sentence with quotes inside. I've rephrased the last 2 rules for clarity.

Comment: So, will full stops be inside quotes or outside them?

Comment: I added an image link to my question with the desired output. Perhaps it will make more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/rT3iZ4/5)

```
((?![.\n\s])[^.\n"]*(?:"[^\n"]*[^\n".]"[^.\n"]*)*(?:"[^"\n]+\."|\.|(?=\n)))
```

Splitting it up:

- `(?![.\n\s])` - First check we are starting with a valid character (not whitespace or the end of a sentence.
- `[^.\n"]*` - Then match any text not surrounded in quotes which does not contain a sentence terminator.
- `(?:"[^\n"]*[^\n".]"[^.\n"]*)` - Then match (in a non-capturing group) a quote that contains at least one character and does not contain a newline and does not end the quote with a sentence terminator - followed by zero-or-more characters which are not in a quote and do not contain a sentence terminator.
- `*` - the previous non-capturing group can be repeated zero (so that there can be sentences without quotes) -or-more times.
- `(?:"[^"\n]+\."|\.|(?=\n))` - finally, include either a quote which terminates with a full stop or the full stop at the end of the sentence or check that we are ending with a newline.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt but you are running in the same problem as me, your regex gives one match for `"They were invited," she said uncertainly, "for the tourney. I don’t..." Alayne closed her book.`  but it should give 2.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is extremely hard to impossible with a simple regex. It would be better to write a parser, since that would be much easier in the given case.

What you have to do is the following:

- You need two modes: "within quotation marks" or "outside of quotation marks"
- Start with "outside of quotation marks"
- If you encounter a quotation mark, toggle between the modes
- If you encounter a punctuation mark in the "outside of quotation marks"-mode break the match here and start a new match
- If you encounter a punctuation mark in the "within quotation marks"-mode check if the next character is a quotation mark. If it is, break the match here, start a new match and set the mode to "outside of quotation marks"

This should give you what you want.