# REGEX to separate sentences

Tags: javascript, regex

A couple days ago, I [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31046831/5048102) for some help. I was trying to create a regex that would separate sentences in a text, and after some good answers, succeeded in putting this together:

`/(("[^\n"]*\n)|("[^\n."]*\.[^\n"]*")|(?=[^\n ])("[^\n."]*")?([^\n. ]| (?!"))*( "[^\n."]*"([^\n. ]| (?!"))*)*( "[^\n"]*("|[^\n](?=\n))|\.|[^\n](?=\n)|$))/gi`

Which meets my full list of requirements:

- A sentence ends with a period `.` or a newline character `\n`
- A sentence may contain any number of quotes
- A quote starts with a space  and a double quotation mark `"` except when found at the beginning of a sentence in which case the space shall be ignored
- A quote ends with a double quotation mark `"`
- A quote may have any number of periods `.` without immediately ending the sentence containing it. If a period is found in a quote, the sentence will wait until the quote is closed with a double quotation mark `"` to end
- A quote immediately ends when a newline character is encountered `\n` in which case the sentence containing the quote also immediately ends

Here is my test case: [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/dA9qY8/1)

Now this is just the beginning and I intend to expand it. I'll have to escape periods when they are used numerically (for example `5.4`). I may also want to treat parenthesis pairs `()` like quotes.

But I am starting to seriously doubt my approach. Is a regex the way to go? Someone in my previous post suggested using a parser. I've done some research and I do not understand the hate for regular expressions on the web. They do the job exactly as intended. If there is another better/faster/cleaner way, I'd love some pointers on how to achieve that.

Comment: If `regex` does exactly what you want it to do then why would you seriously doubt your approach? Yes, there are a lot of people that believe there's one way to do things, but don't let that discourage you. Maybe `regex` isn't the right approach for this particular purpose — maybe it is. Until there's something compelling to tell you otherwise then use whatever method seems to work for you effectively.

Comment: Do you find your current regex readable? Complicated regexes aren't looked down upon because they can't do the task, but rather because they quickly get out of hand.

Answer (score 0):

Your first regex looks really complicated for this job, I believe the following one should cover the same cases:

```
(?:"[^"\r\n]+"|[^.\r\n])+[.\r\n]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Visualization on [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/O63GHypSJhUXpmtO)

Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eE8jY9/1)

---

Now for your new requirements:

```
(?:"[^"\r\n]+"|\([^)\r\n]+\)|\d\.\d|[^.\r\n])+[.\r\n]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Visualization on [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/gzBNHeEw2w5ggOWk)

Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nF7bG9/1)

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for an alternative to regex if there is one, and also your implementation doesn't meet all requirements, `"Send them away. I never asked them here." Mya looked nonplussed.` gives you a single match but there should be 2. On the test case I have 31 matches and you have 26.